# How can I fix this error? This is not my code, this code is an extension for an app I love playing

Tags: java, macos, jar

I am running a .jar file on my macbook through terminal, as it will not load directly by me clicking it even though i have all the latest java updates. When i click the .jar file, I receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at YSFlightMU.<init>(YSFlightMU.java:169)
at YSFlightMU.main(YSFlightMU.java:2507)
```

I have read through a number of the Q&A's on the site; however, I still couldn't fix the issue. The two lines with issues (168 & 2507) are:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dir.length; i++)
```

and

```
YSFlightMU ysfmu = new YSFlightMU();
```

Comment: `dir` may be null.

Comment: I thought that Shree Krishna, but I wasn't able to find it in the code...I'd post the code here but it's pretty lengthy

Comment: Now it is marked duplicate, No need of that bro.

Comment: @VERNONARRINGTON - In fact, if the symptoms are as you have reported, then the >>only plausible explanation<< is that `dir` is `null`.

Comment: I thought that too...I made a number of changes to the code (after saving to another file first of course) and read all the null pointer exceptions here and on other sites and I wasn't able to find out why still.